# Como puedo obtener los datos del usuario en sesión

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Quisiera saber si pudieran ayudarme, estoy creando un formulario de solicitudes en base al siguiente modelo

```
public class NuevaSolicitudViewModel
{
    public int IdSolicitud { get; set; }
    public int Expediente { get; set; }
    public int IdEmpleadoAlta { get; set; }
    public int IdEmpleadoOrigen { get; set; }
    public int IdEmpleadoDestino { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<int, string> Destino { get; set; }
    public int IdCoche { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime FechaSolicitud { get; set; }
    public int Estado { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime CambioEstado { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Resuelto { get; set; }
}
```

Lo que quisiera hacer es lo siguiente, como pueden ver tengo 3 referencias al empleados "alta,origen y destino" en los cuales alta tiene que ser el usuario actual con el que estoy logueado "por control" origen es el usuario que hizo la solicitudes "practicamente será el mismo que el de alta" y destino "lista de empleados al que voy a hacerle la solicitud".

De que manera puedo obtener el usuario de alta y destino a través de la sesión?

Aqui les dejo mi controlador Login

```
public class LoginController : Controller
{
    // GET: Login
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult Entrar(String usuario, String contraseña)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var db = new sir_cjfEntities())
            {
                var lst = from d in db.empleados
                          where d.usuario.Equals(usuario.Trim()) && d.contrasena.Equals(contraseña.Trim())  && d.estado == true
                          select d;
                if (lst.Count() > 0)
                {
                    empleados oUser = lst.First();
                    Session["user"] = oUser;
                    return Content("1");
                }
                else
                {
                    return Content("Usuario y/o Contraseña Incorrectos");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Content("Ocurrio un error" + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Este es el get y el post que estoy usando actualmente

```
public ActionResult Agregar()
    {
        var model = new NuevaSolicitudViewModel
        {
            Destino = new Dictionary<int, string>()
        };
        using (var db = new sir_cjfEntities())
        {
            model.Destino = db.empleados.ToDictionary(x => x.id_empleado, x => x.nombre + " " + x.ap_paterno + " " + x.ap_materno);
        }
        return View(model);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Agregar(NuevaSolicitudViewModel model)
    {
        var db = new sir_cjfEntities();
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            model.Destino = db.empleados.ToDictionary(x => x.id_empleado, x => x.nombre + " " + x.ap_paterno + " " + x.ap_materno);
            return View(model);
        }
        var soli = new solicitudes_estac();
        using (db)
        {
            model.FechaSolicitud = DateTime.Now;
            model.CambioEstado = DateTime.Now;
            model.Destino = db.empleados.ToDictionary(x => x.id_empleado, x => x.nombre + " " + x.ap_paterno + " " + x.ap_materno);
            soli.estado = 1;
            soli.id_empleado_alta = model.IdEmpleadoAlta;//obtener la informacion del usuario logueado
            soli.id_empleado_origen = model.IdEmpleadoOrigen;//quien hace la solicitud
            soli.id_empleado_destino = model.IdEmpleadoDestino;//a quien va dirigida?
            soli.id_coche = model.IdCoche; //tengo que obtener el coche registrado por el usuario destino"
            soli.fecha_solicitud = model.FechaSolicitud;
            soli.fecha_cambio_estado = model.CambioEstado;
            db.solicitudes_estac.Add(soli);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        return Redirect(Url.Content("~/CSolicitudes/"));
    }
```

Entonces como podría llenar automáticamente la información del usuario de alta y el de origen?
Agradecería mucho su ayuda, ya que estoy algo atorado con esto

**EDIT 1**

dejo la vista que tengo por el momento

```html
@model SistemadeInformaciónRegional.Models.ViewModels.NuevaSolicitudViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Nueva Solicitud";

}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">

        @using (Html.BeginForm("Agregar", "CSolicitudes", FormMethod.Post, new { }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.ValidationMessage("Error", new { @class = "text-danger", @type = "text" })

            @Html.LabelFor(d => d.IdEmpleadoAlta)<!--este quiero que se llene automanticamente con el nombre del usuario que esta en la sesión-->
            @Html.TextBoxFor(d => d.IdEmpleadoAlta, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessage("IdEmpleadoAlta", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <br />
            @Html.LabelFor(d => d.IdEmpleadoOrigen)<!-- De ser posible también este que se obtenga con el usuario en sesión-->
            @Html.TextBoxFor(d => d.IdEmpleadoOrigen, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessage("IdEmpleadoOrigen", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <br />
            @Html.LabelFor(d => d.IdEmpleadoDestino)
            @Html.DropDownListFor(d => d.IdEmpleadoDestino, new SelectList(Model.Destino, "Key", "Value"),
          new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessage("IdEmpleadoDestino", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <br />
            @Html.LabelFor(d => d.IdCoche)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(d => d.IdCoche, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessage("ApMaterno", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <br />
            <div style="text-align:right;">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Regitrarse" />
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

como pueden ver estoy pidiendo por el momento el usuario a través del ID en el texbox.

**Edit 2**
Estructura de la tabla empleados
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
public partial class empleados
{
    public empleados()
    {
        this.coches = new HashSet<coches>();
        this.estacionamiento = new HashSet<estacionamiento>();
        this.solicitudes_estac = new HashSet<solicitudes_estac>();
        this.solicitudes_estac1 = new HashSet<solicitudes_estac>();
        this.solicitudes_estac2 = new HashSet<solicitudes_estac>();
    }

    public int id_empleado { get; set; }
    public string nombre { get; set; }
    public string ap_paterno { get; set; }
    public string ap_materno { get; set; }
    public int id_organo { get; set; }
    public int id_puesto { get; set; }
    public string usuario { get; set; }
    public string contrasena { get; set; }
    public int permisos { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> estado { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<coches> coches { get; set; }
    public virtual organos organos { get; set; }
    public virtual puestos puestos { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<estacionamiento> estacionamiento { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<solicitudes_estac> solicitudes_estac { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<solicitudes_estac> solicitudes_estac1 { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<solicitudes_estac> solicitudes_estac2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar la vista de `ActionResult Agregar()` por favor?

Comment: Si claro, de hecho voy a subir algunas cosas que corregí del modelo "estoy viendo que los tengo mal aquí"

Comment: Muy bien, ahora, necesito un dato más: Lo que tienes en la sesion `oUser;` es decir, la estructura de esa clase

Comment: Creo que te refieres a eso no? al modelo del dominio